# How to not show each product card if object is empty?

Tags: arrays, typescript, object, if-statement, handlebars.js

I have a carousel that auto populates data based on the context object in the payload preview in a tool I use called IAS. Each object has a product array with data inside of it. However if the product array is empty, I don't want the carousel to show at all. I tried to do the below in my **Handlebars** but even when there was product data, nothing showed :( .

```
{{#if products}}
{{#each products}}
<ul>
    <li class="pr__item-wrapper">
<p class="pr__title">{{attributes.name.value}}</p>
</li>
</ul>
{{/each}}
{{/if}}
```

When product data is available, it is set up like this:

```
"products" : {
  "attributes":{

    "imageUrl": {
    "value": "https://us.devirobot.com/dw/image/v2/BFXP_DEV/on/demandware.static/-/Sites- 
     master-catalog-irobot/default/dwb8b39e90/images/large/roomba/j755020_1.jpg?sw=1800"
  },
    "subheader": {
    "value": null
  },
    "savingsAmount": {
    "value": "100"
  },
    "name": {
    "value": "iRobot Roomba j7+ Robot Vacuum, iRobot Roomba Replenishment Kit for j & i 
     Series & Replacement Dirt Disposal Bags, 3-Pack"
  }
}
}
```

However, sometimes product data will return empty:

```
"products" : [
]
```

When it's empty, I don't want the unordered list to show. Does my if statement need to be modified, or do I need a boolean to return "true" if product data is coming in?

Comment: `products` may be an object or it may be an empty array?!

Comment: My advice would be to make `products` a consistent type - ie., it should _always_ be an array.

Comment: @76484 unfortunately i am not in control of the data. it looks like it turns into an array when empty.

Comment: I don't understand how an object like the one you have posted can be the basis of a carousel. It seems there can only ever be one `attributes.imageUrl.value`. So does your carousel only have at most one image?

Comment: Anyway, I don't think your question is correct because the `#each` won't be a problem in the empty array case (because there will be no items to iterate). When `products` is the object you have shared, the way to access the name would be `{{../products.attributes.name.value}}`.